# How to print fetched result in FastSQLite, there is no .cursor() like in SQLite3?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3-python

I downloaded [`FastSQLite`](https://pypi.org/project/fastsqlite/) for python , [`Readme`](https://github.com/perseoq/FastSQLite/blob/main/README.md)
I created a database and table, but I do not know how to print fetched results, in sqlite3 there is a .cursor() to print results, in FastSQLite there is no `.cursor()` method

```
from fastsqlite import FastSQLite
import pandas as pd

db = FastSQLite()
db.connect('file.db')
db.create_table('gato', 'id int, rum varchar(300)')


db.insert('gato', 'id, rum', '1,123')
db.insert('gato', 'id, rum', '2,223')
db.insert('gato', 'id, rum', '3,323')
db.insert('gato', 'id, rum', '4,423')


table=db.fetch_all('gato')


print ()
print("===========================")  
print(pd.DataFrame(table))
print("===========================")
print ()
```

I checked the database. It is not empty!
Output:

```
===========================
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
===========================
```

Comment: Did you try reading the source code? You'd see that `db.fetch_all()` is simply a wrapper that returns the result of `self.cursor.fetchall()`. So that should have worked.

Comment: I wouldn't use that module. It's poorly designed, poorly written, and poorly documented, and doesn't offer any obvious benefit over anything else.

Comment: It also doesn't use prepared statements with parameters, making it ripe for SQL-injection.